# Send SMS from Marketing Cloud without adding contact in All Contacts

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, mobileconnect, sms

Is there an API Call that allows me to send an SMS from Marketing Cloud without adding a new contact into All Contacts?

I tried to use this [one](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postMessageContactSend.htm), but a new contact has been created and subscripted to the keyword.
    {
        "mobileNumbers": [
        "13175551212"
        ],
        "Subscribe": true,
        "Resubscribe": true,
        "keyword": "JOINSMS",
        "Override": true,
        "messageText": "Welcome to Code@",
    }

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to send to just a number via Marketing Cloud, all recipients need to exist in MobileConnect contacts first.

If recipient doesn't exist, then after sending an SMS via API or Journey Builder it will be added with number opted in to the default keyword.

If you do not want Contacts to exist in MobileConnect at all, then you can have an API activity that will remove the Contact after SMS has been sent. 
This means you will lose all SMS history for that number/contact though.